# Rodar Python e C# juntos

Tags: c#, python, .net, script

Como posso no C# importar, ou seja, executar algum *script* em outra linguagem (Python)?

Exemplo:
Se escrever "R" em um programa em C#, executa um arquivo se chamado `ApertouR.py`.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem como importar, ambas linguagens não tem relação alguma, agora ser quer disparar a execução de um Python através de um script c# então a história é diferente, é possivel

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Exemplo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start("python", @"c:\pasta\arquivo.py");
    }
}
```

Se `python` não estiver instalado globalmente (nas variáveis de ambiente), então faça assim:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\pasta_da_instalacao_do_python\python.exe", @"c:\pasta\arquivo.py");
```

Se quiser pegar o output/resposta faça conforme

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\pasta\arquivo.py";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //Pega saída de erros
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //Pega a saída        
process.Start();

StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(output);

process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Fonte:

- [ProcessStartInfo.StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)
- [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Tem o [Python.NET](https://pythonnet.github.io/) e dever ser o mais adequado. Em alguns casos pode usar o [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). Desta forma as duas linguagens podem funcionar na mesma plataforma e coexistirem.

Tem outras formas, mas acho muito gambiarra. Uma delas é chamar o interpretador externamente como uma aplicação normal. Muita coisa pode sair errado nisto. É uma opção válida, mas não é das mais confiáveis.

Seria bom pensar se precisa mesmo disto, se não tem uma solução melhor. Não podemos ajudar muito mais porque a pergunta não diz o cenário onde será usado. Pode ser que nem precise do Python.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer uma chamada de sistema

```
Process.start(@"python C:\ApertouR.py")
```

Mas não sei que tipo de aplicação é esta.