# É possível utilizar C# e Python no mesmo executável?

Tags: c#, python, interface

Quero criar um software executável para desktop e estou utilizando Python, porém a interface gráfica gostaria de fazer no C#, visto que é muito mais pratico e bonito. Como eu posso correlacionar a interface gráfica no C# com o código criado em Python? Caso não for possível, onde posso fazer essa interface gráfica?

Comment: IronPython seria uma opção, mas acho que é um projeto que está meio devagar, semi-abandonado.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro em qual parte você utiliza o python mas estou assumindo que seria o backend.

Nesse caso você poderia criar um servidor HTTP para troca de informações via API:

[Criação de uma API Rest com Python](https://nataniel-paiva.medium.com/cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-api-rest-com-python-76696d17bfb9)

Outra forma seria criar os scripts que tu precisa em python e fazer com que o C# os rode passando por parametro os valores:

[Como executo um script Python a partir de c #?](https://qastack.com.br/programming/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c)

[Rodar Python e C# juntos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265445/rodar-python-e-c-juntos)